# Sessão sem o www e com o www php

Tags: php, session

Olá,

Estou tendo um problema, acontece que ao usuário logar na pagina www.meusite.com.br a sessão dele não fica em meusite.com.br, por que tem essa diferença de sem www e com www?

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Estou setando a sessão normalmente

session_start();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem haver com o domínio. Alguns domínios são nativamente seusite.com.br ou www.seusite.com.br .

Tente configurar o CNAME de sua hospedagem. Alguns DNSs devem apontar para lugares diferentes. Consequentemente gerando sessões diferente.

Comment: E como eu faço isso? No cpanel, eu fui em Editor de zonas avançado, e lá tem assim:

Comment: Tipo

Nome

TTL

CNAME:

Comment: Vê se acha uma opção chamada @A name

Comment: Não tem esse @A name

Comment: Se sua empresa de domínio não te dá muita opção de configuração de DNS, tente a solução do membro Wallace abaixo.

Comment: Se não funcionar, tente um redirecionamento forçado de domínio pelo htacces . Ou configure seu algoritmo PHP para não aceitar sessões de URL indesejada. Existem funções no PHP para captura de url. Mas eu tentaria pelo htacces.

Comment: Fiz pelo htacess mesmo url forçada

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha funcionado. Cole aqui a configuração htacces para que futuros membros com o mesmo problema possam ter uma ideia de como resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Especifique um diretório onde ambos poderão salvar a sessão. Para isso, utilize [session_save_path()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-save-path.php). Dê uma lida na documentação, a sintaxe ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
    <?php 
    ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));
    session_start();
?>
```

Comment: Não funcionou, coloquei como vc escreveu

Comment: verifique se o caminho de /../session está correto, se a pasta não existir, crie uma